# Objectify at GWT entry point

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify, entry-point

I'm very new to Google Web Toolkit (GWT) and Google Apps Engine. I want to use Objectify directly in the entry point so that I can utilize GWT in my apps. (I use java)

Is it possible to load Objectify entities directly to the entry points without using any call to server side? I've read several tutorials about this topic but all of them either make a RPC call or use other servlet instead.

OR

Is there anyway to use GWT classes (such as Label, Textbox etc) in a servlet outside the entry point?

I am okay if any of the questions above answered. This is a quite general question, so if you have any reference for them I will appreciate it as well. Let me know if I need to add anything, and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

GWT apps run on the client not the server. Objectify however is server side.

GWT will have to use some way to communicate with the server. Technically it would be possible to write a library like Objectify that does that all automatically for you but that would not be a very good idea as it would require to much communication between the client and the server. The client should send high level commands/queries to the server and let the server do most of the work.